# Prove that the integral is a polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$f$ is a continuous real function on $[0,1]$. $Q(t)= (1-(t^2))^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer and $t$ is a real number. If $x$ belongs to $[0,1]$, prove that the integral of $f(t)Q(t-x)$ over $[0,1]$ is a polynomial in $x$.

This a step in Rudin's proof of Weierstrass theorem that I cannot understand.
Kindly help.

Comment: What did you try? Can you see the result, say, for the constant function $f$?

Comment: I have tried integration by parts. I can see the result for constant f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $$Q(t)= (1-(t^2))^n$$, we get $$Q(t-x)= (1-((t-x)^2))^n $$

which is a polynomial in t and x.

Thus the product $f(t)Q(t-x)$ is a sum of terms , $ f(t)t^m x^k $.

When you integrate with respect to t, and evaluate from $0$ to $1$,  the $t's$ disappear and the powers of $x$ stays to make a polynomial  in $x$.